# Node.js how to set server environment PORT and NODE_ENV?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, express

How do I set the server environment to a certain port?

For instance,

```
const app = require('express')()
const isProd = (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
```

I will always get `false` for `isProd` and `3000` for `port`

I don't see the usefulness of these two lines and I can just set them below manually:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  const data = {message: 'Hello World!'}
  return res.status(200).json(data);
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 3030!')
})
```

Do I need some config file in my root?

Any ideas?

I am using Linux/ Ubuntu/ Kubuntu.

Comment: where are you hosting your production build?

Comment: Are you setting the relavant environmental variables on the production server?

Comment: maybe take a look at this for ideas how to do it on your local: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv 

Also recommended to learn what `process.env` actually is

Comment: on linux-based systems just type `export NODE_ENV=production` and `export PORT=8080` from the command line

Comment: @canaanseaton I am using a host from Linode for an instance.

Comment: @canaanseaton in Linode, you get to install everything by yourself, including the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try running your server using below command

```
set NODE_ENV=production && set PORT=7000 && node server.js
```

Or for Linux

```
NODE_ENV=production PORT=7000 node server.js
```

This will set environment and port for your Node server.

Comment: Why not `NODE_ENV=production PORT=7000 node server`?

Comment: Yes it will, but why do you _set_ environment variables?

Comment: For Windows system we need to set those variables before running application.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do I have to do it with a command line from the terminal? Can I use a config file for instance?

Comment: You need to do it from command line although you can create batch or shell script which read configuration from file does this operation..

Answer (score 2):

Depends a bit on where you're hosting (e.g. windows or *nix) and how you're running your app (as a Windows or Linux service, using pm2, using systemd, etc).

The simplest way is to just change the command line call you start your app with, eg (linux):

```
NODE_ENV=prod PORT=34567 node myapp.js
```

or Windows

```
set NODE_ENV=prod && set PORT=34567 && node myapp.js
```

If you're using systemd or pm2 (and you should be), then they each have config files that allow you to set those variables for the environment the server is running in.

Pm2 docs: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Locally,  you can just set defaults in your environment through normal means (in *nix that means exporting them in your shell config)

Comment: I am using a host from Linode for an instance.  in Linode, you get to install everything by yourself, including the server. I will be using pm2.

Comment: do I have to do it with a command line from the terminal? Can I use a config file for instance? I use Linux.

Comment: Yes, you can do it with pm2 config file, there's a place for environment variables http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/